# Micrometer Prometheus metrics in jersey application (Non spring)

Tags: java, prometheus, jersey-2.0, micrometer

I have a web application (war) with Jersey REST endpoints. I am integrating with prometheus / micrometer for generating metrics. I have exposed "/metrics" endpoint as in here

```
@Path("/metrics")
public class Metrics {
    private static final PrometheusMeterRegistry prometheusRegistry = new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);

    static {
        new JvmGcMetrics().bindTo(prometheusRegistry);
        new JvmMemoryMetrics().bindTo(prometheusRegistry);
        new JvmCompilationMetrics().bindTo(prometheusRegistry);
        new JvmThreadMetrics().bindTo(prometheusRegistry);
    }
    @GET
    public String getMetrics() {
        return prometheusRegistry.scrape();
    }
}
```

I am stuck on how to generate http request metrics. I could not find any code that would relevant to get these metrics. Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Just to be clear, your JVM metrics are being published correctly to Prometheus. And you are looking to record HTTP Requests and expose those as metrics?

Comment: Yes, that's right. There isn't a straightforward way to achieve. Just came across https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/master/micrometer-jersey2. Have you tried this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to include a `Filter` to record each request as it comes through. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsFilter.java for how Spring does it.

I would recommend against using a `static` registry if possible and using dependency injection instead.

Here is a tiny example of what you might do within a filter's `doFilter` method

```
        long start = System.nanoTime()
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            long durationNanos = System.nanoTime() - start;
            prometheusRegistry.timer("http.server.requests", "status", response.getStatus().toString()).record(durationNanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Equivalent exception timer recording
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: If you happen to use Tomcat or Jetty, you can use their MeterBinders to add a few additional meters (e.g.: TomcatMetrics) too.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively to what [checketts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970308/checketts) proposed, you could make use of the Jersey server instrumentation of Micrometer which is present even prior to the `1.0.0` release in the form of `micrometer-jersey2` library. You can find the source [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/1.6.x/micrometer-jersey2).

Your entrypoint to this is the [`MetricsApplicationEventListener`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/1.6.x/micrometer-jersey2/src/main/java/io/micrometer/jersey2/server/MetricsApplicationEventListener.java) which can be registered with Jerseys `ResourceConfig`. For an example, you can have a look at the [test class](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/1.6.x/micrometer-jersey2/src/test/java/io/micrometer/jersey2/server/MetricsRequestEventListenerTest.java#L55) on how this could be done.

You can also have a look at how this is integrated/autoconfigured in Spring Boot [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.4.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/jersey/JerseyServerMetricsAutoConfiguration.java).

One last note: Spring Boots metric name is `http.server.requests` (to distinguish them from HTTP client request metrics) and if you one day will move to Spring Boot or your platform is already running Spring Boot applications, your non Spring Boot HTTP requests metrics will nicely match without further ado.

Comment: I updated my example to use the `http.server.requests` naming in case someone else copies code off Stack Overflow and never changes it...

Comment: @ mweiranch, is there a way to skip some URIs from being measured? For e.g, health check and the metrics endpoint.

Comment: The above answer is correct as well. If someone is adopting the above, please make sure you use ExceptionMapper for tranforming exceptions to appropriate HTTP response codes.

Comment: @DBS just register an appropriate Micrometer `MeterFilter` with the used `MeterRegistry`. (`registry.config().meterFilter(...)`)